# useState with array of JSON objects, undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

I am using a state variable for my JSON data. I get the following error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating posts[0])`. `typeof(posts)` is `object` even though posts is an array. I can go as deep as I want with the plain JSON object but once I access my data as a state variable React Native bugs out. Code:

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  var dataRetrieved = false;

  const getData = async () => {
    await fetchPosts();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!dataRetrieved) {
      dataRetrieved = true;
      getData();
    }
  }, []);

  const fetchPosts = useCallback(async () => {
    fetch('https://www.generic.com/api/feed', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        page: 1,
      })
    })
    .then((response)=> response.json())
    .then((json)=> {
      setPosts(json.posts);
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
      console.log(error);
    })
  });

  return (
    <FlatList contentContainerStyle={styles.gridWrap}
      ListHeaderComponent={
      <>
        <Text>
          {JSON.stringify(posts[0])}
        </Text>
        ...
```

Comment: Where are you accessing posts[0] ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I access it in a class component. I updated the code to show how I am debugging.

Comment: Still there is no code having posts[0] so hard to know the actual problem

Comment: I get the same error with the code shown

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem

```
 <Text>
      {JSON.stringify(posts[0])}
    </Text>
```

This occurs in your first render, your useEffect is not run yet and the array is not loaded from the api. When the render is called for the first time array is empty and accessing the first element will throw the error.

The fix that you can do is the show the ActivityIndicator

like

```
If(posts.length===0)
 return <ActivityIndicator/>
```

Or you can compare inside the render for the length of the array and render.

Answer (score 1):

This is happened as render method was called before the post variable is loaded with the data.

you can solve it by conditional rendering by checking whether data is present or not.

```
{ posts && posts.length
  <Text>
   {JSON.stringify(posts[0])}
 </Text>
}
```

it will check whether posts is undefined or not and if it is not then it renders the text component

Comment: this will cause the same issue posts is an array so you have to do posts && posts.length && <...>

Comment: yes, as it initially contain empty string and truthy value of empty array is true , you need to check for length too.